# What is the difference between vertical pipe and juxtaposition in JQ?

Tags: json, jq, syntax

My program returns `JSON` into `stdout` and it is an object with `operations` field, which contains a list of operations. Each operation contains fields including `id` fields, for example:

```
{
    "operations": [
        {
            "id": "694ef895-793f4631-41103e8-8ab59e66",
```

I am trying to get a list of ids from this with `jq`.

If I am writing

```
jq '.operations | .[] | .id'
```

it works, and if I am wiritng

```
jq '.operations | .[].id'
```

it works too.

I.e. juxtaposition is the same as `|` here.

But if I write

```
jq '.operations.[].id'
```

it fails with message

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or
>   QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
>   .operations.[].id             jq: 1 compile error

why and how to fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you are only comparing `.foo.bar` and `|`, there's no difference, as the man-page says under "BASIC FILTERS":

> A filter of the form `.foo.bar` is equivalent to `.foo|.bar`.

And yes, you need `.operations[].id` in your case.

Comment: For anyone wondering about the last example command in the question, or a similar error, note that there's no `.` between `.operations` and the following `[]` ('index all') filter.